# Passing in arguments to pthread results in duplicates C

Tags: c, multithreading, file-io, pthreads

For an assignment I'm supposed to use `pthread` to create a multithreaded version of grep called search (that is recursive), where the arguments are `./search pattern ~/dir ~/dir2 ~/dir3.. etc`. Also the assignment specifically states that I am supposed to use `pthread_exit(NULL)` at the end to join all the threads and I am supposed to create a thread for each file I open. This means that the output can be jumbled as long as each line found is on a seperate line. This means the output could look something like this, when I pass in two of the same file with the search pattern `Hello`:

```
$ ./search Hello ~/files/file2.txt ~/files/file.txt

2 ~/files/file.txt Hello world 4
1 ~/files/file2.txt Hello there 9
^           ^            ^      ^
argument #, file found, line, line #
```

I've got it to work without multithreading and everything seems normal. However I'm having trouble getting the argument structure I pass into `pthread_create` to actually pass in the right things.

I have a method called `create_file_thread` that takes in the file name to be opened, and the index of the argument it's at. I then have a global variable structure called `thread_array` that looks like this:

```
struct thread_struct {
    char file_name[256];
    int arg_id;
};
struct thread_struct thread_array[200];
```

I store the file_name and index passed into `create_file_thread` into this structure, and then pass that into `pthread_create`, like so:

```
void create_file_thread(char *file_name, int i)
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS]; // NUM_THREADS = 200
    strcpy(thread_array[i].file_name, file_name);
    thread_array[i].arg_id = i + 1; // offset i
    int rc;
    if((rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, grep_file, &thread_array[i])))    
        exit(-1); // error
}
```

Just to make sure, I printed out `thread_array[i].file_name` every time it was called and it would end up giving me the correct file name.

And here is a simplified version of `grep_file()` (as a test I'm just printing out the file name passed in):

```
void * grep_file(void *arg)
{
    struct thread_struct *thread = arg;
    char file_name[256];
    strcpy(file_name, thread->file_name);
    int id = thread->thread_id;
    printf("File name: %s\n", file_name);
    return NULL;
}
```

If I passed in `~/files/file.txt` as argument 1, and `~/files/file2.txt` as argument 2, I should see this as output:

```
File name: ~/files/file.txt
File name: ~/files/file2.txt
```

However, I end up with this:

```
File name: ~/files/file.txt
File name: ~/files/file.txt
```

The weird part is, is that sometimes I'll get the correct output, but most of the time I'll get a repeat of the first argument given. Since it only creates two threads, I end up getting the same output twice, instead of having two outputs with different file names. How can I stop getting the argument structure passed into `grep_file` to stop repeating?

Edit:

Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/QWSFh9Zh

As a warning it's pretty messy because of a few (stupid) restrictions (like functions can not be more than 5 lines.. I'm breaking this rule for the sake of just trying to get this to work).

Comment: The only thing odd in `create_file_thread` is the local variable `pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];` You only use one entry in that array, and the array promptly disappears as soon as the function returns. Otherwise, there's nothing wrong with what you're doing. The problem can only be in the function that calls `create_file_thread`, which is probably `main`.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code that calls `create_file_thread`?

Comment: @caf I added all of the code.. sorry it's a bit long but the only things that relate to multi threading are create_file_thread, grep_file, and main. I also commented out where I was opening files, instead it just prints the file name passed in.

Comment: @user3386109 I've added all of my code. As I explained above, the only thing that does multi threading is `create_file_thread`, `grep_file`, and `main`. Also, that is weird.. I'm going off of my professor's example though, unfortunately I'm brand new to this.

Comment: @Alex: As a tangential comment while I look at your code, you shouldn't define identifiers `_DIR` and `_FILE` - identifiers that start with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved to the implementation, in all contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not seeing a problem with passing individual files, but if you pass directories containing multiple files, `grep_directory()` will start multiple threads with the same value of `id`, which will all store their filename in the same place.

Comment: Ohhh.. that makes sense now. I noticed though that even doing `grep_directory()` and opening files results in the correct amount of threads created. How should I handle the issue of passing the same id? Can I just do `grep_file(entry_path, id+1)`?

Comment: @Alex: You could make the "next thread ID" a global variable declared next to `thread_array`.  Then you wouldn't pass `i` to `create_file_thread` - it would instead just do `int i = next_id++;`

Comment: Thanks for your help! Something weird is happening now though. For whatever reason, if I have multiple directories as an argument, it will only loop once. However if I have my arguments as files, everything will output correctly. Any idea as to what could be causing this?

Comment: Nevermind! I figured it out, I didn't have enough threads created for all of the files being opened, so it would stop prematurely. Thanks again for looking at my code.